# why my android studio is indexing many times endlessly?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I changed my root folder name ,after that my app loaded on emulator perfectly but after a short time my android studio begin indexing endlessly and uninterrupted.Then after about 10 min,it show `"Gradle sync finished in 12s 851ms (from cached state)"` in event log.what's the problem?

I have android studio 3.1.2 and my IDE has worked well until now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with invalidating cache and restart in File tab option.